# CSS button like vertical align feature

Tags: html, css, button, flexbox

### Pre History

I am building html form, with elements having multiple options ...., but instead of showing it as dropdown, i would like to show them as buttons without using any js, I removed buttons with label pointing to input checkbox.

### Problem

I need `label` (or `anchor` or `div`) tag behave exactly like `button` tag without any extra wrapper tags, I googled all variation doesn't provide same result as native tag button.

```html
<button class="button">
  Text
  <div>Small Text</div>
</button>
```

### Solutions  not work

`line-height, padding` does not provide same functionality, because button height/width and text length may vary. I tried special webkit style `-webkit-appearance: button;` no changes.

### Mustery Flex

I tried flex

```css
.button {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
 <div class="button">
   Text
   <div>Small Text</div>
 </div>
```

but child `div` inside button not breaking/warping to new line.
p.s Environment tested, Google Chrome, Safari

Comment: could you please provide jsfiddle of your code?

Comment: Looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), why don't you just use `button` if you need to replicate its functionality?

Comment: Button https://jsfiddle.net/s1dqtmLs/, Label https://jsfiddle.net/7vegryym/1/

Comment: @LazarLjubenović I making html form, where i am using multiple select input but appearance would be buttons instead of options, and instead of buttons i will use input checkboxes with labels, checkboxes will be hidden

Comment: `<button>`s can't contain divs...it's invalid HTMl.

Answer (score 2):

I found solution using flex with `flex-direction: column;` so text and div treats like column items, here is code

```
label.button {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center; /* <-- actual veertical align */
    display: inline-flex;
    text-align:center;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fxmdm7e7/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Does this does the job ?

```css
div.button {
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.button div {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
   Text
   <div>Small Text</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ghost element trick looks work well.

```css
.wrap {
  text-align: center;
  background: #ededed;
  margin: 20px;
}
 
.wrap:before {
  content: '\200B';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%; 
  vertical-align: middle;
 }
 
.centered-guy {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: #777 dotted 2px;
  background: #666;
  color: #fff;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrap" style="height: 512px;"> 
    <div class="centered-guy">
        <h1>Some text</h1>
        <p>Bool!<br>Look at me, mama!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```